# how to disable pasting on google form?

Tags: forms

i want to create a google form that i dont want people answer the questions by pasting from somewhere else, I want them to type their answers.

How can I do this?

I have tried to add js codes to google script but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not worh to prevent pasting because it will never be 100% effective, users can tweak prevention and do what they want.

But you can try using javascript.

This will prevent all inputs in your form:

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // This is what prevents pasting.
});
```

And this one will prevent only on an input that is specified by it's ID:

```
window.onload = function (){
    var input = document.getElementById('inputId');
    input.onpaste = functino(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**Update based on your comment**

[Here](https://www.madebymany.com/stories/supercharge-your-google-form-with-google-apps-script) is a complete tutorial on how to create a google form and add scripts to it. It's not the exact same problem, but it's a clue.

Comment: @user6311045 Are you certain you can use plain Javascript here? I'm fairly certain that it only allows Google Script which is rather limited and is a superset of ECMAScript than a superset. Also, I doubt that you can have scripts in the frontend i.e. the part the user sees. Have you tried putting a simple alert or even a console.log that runs when a user opens a form using this method?